# Equality in de Rham cohomology

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, differential-forms

Let $U_1,U_2,...,U_r$ be open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $U_i\cap U_j =\emptyset$ for all $i \neq j$. Then prove, $H^k_{dR}(\bigcup_{i=1}^{r} U_i)=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{r} H^k_{dR} (U_i)$

Comment: Are you familiar with the isomorphism with Cech cohomology/how the latter works?

Comment: No! I just read definition of $H^k_{dR}$ today from some pdf file. And there it was asked to proved just after defining.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if those sets are pairwais disjoint, then everything splits as a direct sum: the $k$-forms $$\Omega^k(\cup_i U_i)\simeq\oplus_i\Omega^k(U_i)$$ is given by $\omega\mapsto (\omega|_{U_i})_i$ and the De Rham differential $d$ respects this splitting. So, both the kernel and image of $d$ respect this splitting as well..

Note, however, that for an infinite number of $U_j$'s the cohomology of $\cup_j U_j$ equals the product of the cohomologies, not the direct sum.

Comment: Can you please explain the step "and the De Rham differential d respects this splitting" .. I'm really beginner and not comfortable yet

Comment: @dragoboy by restriction, each form on the union leads to one form for each of the $r$ sets. Likewise, any set of r$r$ forms, one from each $U_i$ yields a form on their union. The lack of intersection is what allows you to freely choose *any* such collection.

Comment: Hmmm, will this map do the job ? $d^{k}\omega \to (d_{i}^{k}(\omega)|_{U_i})$ where all of $d^{k}_{i}:\Omega^{k}(U_i)\to \Omega^{k+1}(U_i)$ and $d^{k}:\Omega^{k}(\cup U_i)\to \Omega^{k+1}(\cup U_i)$